# Flash player not hiding during jQuery toggle event

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-ui, toggle, show-hide

I am toggling show/hide using jQuery on a div block via

```
$("#videoArea_" + id).fadeToggle(100);
```

and it's working perfectly except for one minor detail.  When there is a flash video player in that content area, the flash player will not hide along with the rest of the block via the "toggle" function.

The strange thing is that it **will** hide the video using the `hide()` function but I'd rather use `toggle()` to keep track of my state and switch accordingly.

Is this a bug in the `toggle()` function or am I forgetting something here?

**Edit:** By the way, it appears to do this only in Google Chrome.  Safari, Firefox, Opera all work fine, so I'm thinking this is a Chrome bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it does not hide, what is its "display" style? It looks like hide() and toggle() both are supposed to use display:none. I wonder something is forcing a different setting. Also, (not sure if it helps), have you set the wmode to opaque for the flash video? I have seen funny things happen when wmode remains as 'window' (the default). Let us know here whatever works. I am curious to know. :)

Comment: I think you are right about the `wmode`... Originally I placed it in the page as an iframe and after you said that I tried it as an embed with the wmode option and now it works fine in Chrome.  Thanks for the suggestion!